# python3 - getting LDAPs attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap

I'am trying find out how to search in LDAP and get attribute in pure form using python (with LDAP3 lib).

Concretly I need value attribute "createtimestamp" in LDAP object "erglobalid=00000000000000000001"

```
from ldap3 import *

server = Server(' ldap://10.46.73.131:3896', get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, 'cn=root', 'password', auto_bind=True, check_names=True)

conn.search('ou=roles,erglobalid=00000000000000000000,ou=CM,DC=TS', '(createtimestamp=*)')
```

...When I print search results I get python object.

```
>>> conn.entries[2]
DN: erglobalid=8226151915966928143,ou=roles,erglobalid=00000000000000000000,ou=CM,dc=TS - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2018-05-09T15:22:22.966676
```

Does anyone know how to gain value in string or date format?

Answer (score 0):

You must specify which attributes you want back in the query using “attributes=[‘createTimestamp’] in the search operation. It should be returned as a date object in the “entries” or responses property of the connection object.